# Вывести число которое повторяется наибольшее количество раз

Tags: javascript

Получил задание: вывести цифру, которая повторяется в числе подряд наибольшее количество раз.

Однако возникла одна проблема. К примеру возьмем такое число - 122233. По идее должно вывестись сообщение "||2||3||". То есть цифра два повторяется три раза. Однако выводится следующее "||3||3||". Значение переменной max сохраняется и все отлично, но значение перемнной s_1 равняется последнему числу. Я пробовал делать еще одну проверку **в** else, типа:

```
if(same != max) {
  delete s_1;
}
```

Но не работало. Помогите пожалуйста, вот код:

```
function same_numbers() {
 var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
 var replaced;
 var same;
 var s_1;
 var arr = [];
 while (number.length) {
  s_1 = number[0];
  replaced = number.split(s_1).join('');
  same = number.length - replaced.length;
  number = replaced;
  if (same == 1) {
    delete s_1;
  }
  else {
   (arr.push(same));
   var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
  }

 }
  alert( "||" + s_1 + "||" + max + "||" );

}
```

Comment: 1. Выясните разницу между числом и цифрой. 2. Возьмите листок бумаги и карандаш и выполните Ваш код на бумаге для данной строки. 3. Вот это "delete s_1;" что делает?

Comment: @Igor удаляет число если оно повторяется всего один раз(что бы легче работать было)

Comment: может alert поднять на уровень? по логике вроде так и должно быть. цикл ведь заканчивается на 3, вот и выводится последнее число

Comment: @Mark_8 "удаляет число" - откуда, "легче" - кому? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: @webDev_ знаю, но в таком случае сообщение будет выводится три раза, а мне нужно всего один

Comment: @Igor прошу прощения, переменную. Может и не легче, просто первое что пришло в голову при написании этой программы это проверка на то, равняется ли значение единице - если да, то сразу отбрасываем это число

Comment: @Mark_8 сделал правку формулировки задачи. И уже только потом подумал, что ты возможно хотел проанализировать просто количество цифр в числе, а не количество цифр - идущих подряд.  Правку одобрили, если что конкретизируй плиз - подправь сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом моменте у вас происходит что то не понятное

> ```
>   if (same == 1) {
>     delete s_1;
>   }
>   else {
>    (arr.push(same));
>    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
>   }
> ```

Если вам не важно какую именно цифру выводить в случае когда несколько максимумов, то можно считать так.

```js
function same_numbers() {
 var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
 var replaced;
 var same;
 var s_1;
 var arr = [];
 var digits = {};

 while (number.length) {
  s_1 = number[0];
  replaced = number.split(s_1).join('');
  same = number.length - replaced.length;
  number = replaced;
  digits[s_1] = same;

 }
  var max_key = null;
  for(var key in digits) {
    if(max_key === null || digits[key] > digits[max_key]) {
      max_key = key;
      }
  }
  alert( "||" + max_key + "||" + digits[max_key] + "||" );

}
```

```html
<input id="number"\>
<button onclick="same_numbers()">calc</button>
```

Comment: 111223331111 - выводит ||1||7|| . Автор спрашивал про "повторяется", поидее должно быть ||1||4|| .

Comment: да, вы правы. Я подумал что "встречается". И код автора считал количество цифр в числе, а не повторений.

Answer (score 2):

Интересное задание! Такое вот решение предлагаю:

```js
var number = 112223322;
var answer = {number : '', count: 0};

(String(number).match(/((0+)|(1+)|(2+)|(3+)|(4+)|(5+)|(6+)|(7+)|(8+)|(9+))/g) || [])
.map(function(val){
  if (val.length > answer.count){
    answer = {number: val.charAt(0), count: val.length};
  }
});
alert("||"+answer.number+"||"+answer.count+"||");
```

А твой код отладить немного сложно - названия переменных не слишком очевидны.

P.S. Надо это задание, или подобное на код-гольф вынести.

UPD:
Надо заметить, приведённый код - анализирует именно последовательности. То есть **максимальное количество цифр, идущих подряд** . Из вопроса не совсем было понятно - надо анализировать просто количество цифр в числе, или количество цифр, идущих подряд.

Comment: Вместо `map` семантичнее было бы использовать `forEach`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, на самом деле тут свертка и нужен был `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

например, вот такое решение:

```
function same_numbers() {
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value;

    var max = number.split('').reduce(function(prev,curr,index,arr){
        return (curr=parseInt(curr),!prev[curr] ? prev[curr]=1 : prev[curr]++, prev);
    }, new Array(10)).reduce(function(prev,curr,index,arr){
        return (curr>prev[1] ?  (prev[1]=curr,prev[0]=index) : 0, prev);
    }, [0,0]); // 0 - index, 1 - val

    alert('||' + max[0] + '||' + max[1] + '||');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам универсальное решение для любых строк

```js
function getMaxChar(AStr) {
  if (AStr == "")
    return;
  var chars = String(AStr).split("");
  chars.sort();
  var counts = new Array();
  counts.push({chr: chars[0], cnt: 1});
  
  for (var i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == chars[i - 1])
      counts[counts.length - 1].cnt++;
    else
      counts.push({chr: chars[i], cnt: 1});
  }

  var maxIdx = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {
    if (counts[i].cnt > counts[maxIdx].cnt)
      maxIdx = i;
  }

  return counts[maxIdx];
}

console.log(getMaxChar(1122234));
console.log(getMaxChar('aaBBBcc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Найдите в строке группы с одинаковыми цифрами и отсортируйте по длине каждой в убывающем порядке. Первой будет искомая группа цифр.

```js
function same_numbers() {
  var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  
  var result = number.split(/(([\s\S])\2*)/).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length > b.length ? -1 : 1;
  })[0];
  alert(["", result, result.length, ""].join("||"));
}
```

```html
<input id="number" value="111223331111">
<button onclick="same_numbers();">Calculate</button>
```